# Get floating value with integer number

Tags: php

I want to add two number.

```
<?php

    $num="11";
    $num2="10";
    echo $num+$num2;  //21

 ?>
```

But i am not able to get this type of output

Ans : 21.00

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Where are you adding integers?

Comment: @PeteR: `$num+$num2`?

Comment: Strictly speaking, adding numeric strings with implicit casting to integer

Comment: @AmalMurali: They're strings.

Comment: @PeteR: But... it's PHP!

Comment: @AmalMurali: I know, I'm just being pedantic. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    $num="11";
    $num2="10";
    $num3= $num+$num2;  //21
echo number_format($num3,2);

 ?>
```

use `number_format()`

demo here http://codepad.org/7tCRpdct